# do all drivers need to register a service?

Tags: windows, service, drivers

As I know, for installing a driver, one can use SCM and installing a serivce for his driver or by using undocumented zwsetsysteminformation.

My question is, does all drivers need to have services if they are not installed using zwsetsysteminfo call?
I see my services in my windows, but some drivers like portcls.sys, TDI.SYS and etc have no services with them. so how they are installed?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there is absolutely no such need.

Many drivers are part of Windows and don't need installation whatsoever. Other drivers are installed when Plug and Play hardware is installed.

Comment: But non plug&play drivers like Beep.sys,http.sys,Partmng.sys,disk.sys and etc have services.